# capistrano + dreamhost + deploy fails doesnt create the release/release_version dir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, dreamhost

i cant get capistrano to fully deploy my rails app to my dreamhost VPS..

as far as i can tell its halting at creating the release directory..

```
$ cap deploy
```

i get

```
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/gasloggr/gasloggr.com/releases/20120824064241 && bundle install --gemfile /home/gasloggr/gasloggr.com/releases/20120824064241/Gemfile --path /home/gasloggr/gasloggr.com/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on gasloggr.com
```

for troubleshooting purposes i ran what was in quotes on the server itself and i received..

```
bash: cd: /home/gasloggr/gasloggr.com/releases/20120824064241: No such file or directory
```

a quick `ls -alh` of the releases dir, and guess what... its empty.

### My deploy.rb file

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'

default_run_options[:pty] = false
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

set :use_sudo, false
set :user, "gasloggr"

set :application, "gasloggr.com"
set :repository,  "git@github.com:gorelative/GasLoggr.git"
set :scm, :git
set :branch, 'master'
set :git_shallow_clone, 1
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :copy_compression, :bz2
set :rails_env, 'production'
set :deploy_to, "/home/gasloggr/#{application}"

role :web, "#{application}"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "#{application}"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "#{application}", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run
# role :db,  "your slave db-server here"

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

i have tried removing `:deploy_via` as well as all of the below:

```
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :deploy_via, :copy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try again following the methods outlined here: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Capistrano

This specific part may be of the most help, mentioning cap deploy:setup : http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Capistrano#Deployment_with_Capistrano